# Which tense to use for the verb following "Do you mind if I..."?

Tags: grammar

At school, I was taught the traditional grammar rules that stated that it was correct to say "as if it were" instead of "as if it was" and that "Do you mind if I" was always to be followed by a past-form verb rather than the present-form one.

However, the more I am exposed to the daily English, the more I hear "as if it was" and questions like "Do you mind if I go there?"

So, my question is: what is grammatically correct, is it

> "Do you mind if I **go** there?"

or still

> "Do you mind if I **went** there?"

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any problem with *do you mind + present.* That said,

> Do you mind if I **go** there?

...is *absolutely* fine!

Nevertheless, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-nouns/mind) describes that had it been *Would you...* it could have taken the past tense.

> Would you mind if I **went** there?

The reference says: *When we ask for permission politely, we can use would you mind if I + past or do you mind if I + present*

Comment: Indeed, "**Do** you mind if I **went** there" seems to me to be mixing the two usages and doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: It isn't past tense, this is [past subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) tense.  It describes an action that is conditional, like "If I were rich, I'd buy a yacht."  In that example, I'm not talking about the past, and neither is the "went" in your example.

Comment: @Neil I generalized it as the dictionary did.

Comment: @MaulikV Right, and I get that.  Just pointing out that the dictionary is wrong.  :)

Comment: I've just come across a site by grammarians from Seattle: https://www.talkenglish.com/lessondetails.aspx?ALID=2048 There are 5+5 (do+would) examples, including 'Do you mind if we _left_ early?' which sounds wrong to me (due to past used). So is it definitely a mistake?

Comment: @Alex_ander - What's funny is if you click on 'Do you mind if we left early?' they still read it as 'Do you mind if we leave early?'    :) :)

Comment: Depending on the context **Do you mind if I went there** can have two meanings: either factual or hypothetical. Same the above comment.